# AWS Kinesis PutMedia Operation for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, ecmascript-6, amazon-kinesis

So I am using the AWS SDK v2, to create a Video Stream where I post my webcam through the browser.

The goal is to do the whole process on an HTML page using scripts, that is because it is a background script of a Chrome Extension.

I have managed to import the SDK's I needed and I want to push my camera video to the server.

The video feed will be processed later in the backend through a Lambda function for machine learning.

```
  const AWS = window.AWS
  const formValues = getFormValues()
  const video = document.getElementById('video')
  var options = {
    accessKeyId: formValues.accessKeyId,
    secretAccessKey: formValues.secretAccessKey,
    sessionToken: formValues.sessionToken,
    region: formValues.region,
    endpdpoint: formValues.endpoint,
  }
  const kinesisVideo = new AWS.KinesisVideo(options)

  async function sendFeedToServer() {
    let streamName = `stream-${getRandomID()}`
    await createVideoStream(streamName)
    setTimeout(() => {
      getEndpoint(streamName, 'PUT_MEDIA')
    }, 1000)
  }

  async function getEndpoint(streamName, operation) {
    var params = {
      APIName: operation,
      // StreamARN: arn,
      StreamName: streamName,
    }
    console.log(params)
    kinesisVideo.getDataEndpoint(params, function (err, data) {
      if (err) console.log(err, err.stack)
      else console.log(data) // endpoint to read and write data
    })
  }

  async function createVideoStream(streamName) {
    const params = {
      StreamName: streamName /* required */,
      // DataRetentionInHours: 'NUMBER_VALUE',
      DeviceName: 'Extension',
      KmsKeyId: 'KmsKeyId',
      // MediaType: 'STRING_VALUE',
      // Tags: {
      //   '<TagKey>': 'STRING_VALUE',
      //   /* '<TagKey>': ... */
      // },
    }
    kinesisVideo.createStream(params, function (err, data) {
      if (err) console.log(err, err.stack)
      // an error occurred
      else console.log(data) // successful response
    })
  }
```

The `sendFeedToServer()` function is fired when the camera is turned on and we have a video stream.

The `getEndpoint()` function returns the endpoint where I can write data.
As described in the API: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/KinesisVideo.html#getDataEndpoint-property

I cannot find a way to `putMedia` using `JavaScript` on the documentation though, am I missing something?

Are there any workarounds in order to implement this in the browser?

Comment: Same issue https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=321161

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is the link for the documentation for PutMedia for using with the endpoint obtained from getEndpoint in above code:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/kinesisvideo/AmazonKinesisVideoPutMedia.html

Comment: The person asked for Javascript, not Java.